# Canonical form and basis of orthogonal operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Find canonical form and canonical basis of orthogonal operator $f$ which has the following matrix in some orthonormal basis $$A_f=\frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

I will show my approach and could you help me to proceed my reasoning, please?

**Approach:** We know that for any orthogonal operator there is a canonical basis such that matrix of the operator $f$ in this basis is $$\begin{bmatrix}
\pm 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi \\
0 & \sin \varphi & \cos \varphi 
\end{bmatrix}.$$ Since the determinant and trace of matrix of linear operator are the same in any basis we make the following remark: since $\det A_f=1$ then in canonical form the first element of the first row should be equal to $1$. Since $\text{tr}A_f=2$ then $2\cos \varphi+1=2 \Leftrightarrow \cos \varphi =\frac{1}{2}$. So $\sin \varphi=\pm \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Also it follows that $1$ is an eigenvalue of operator $f$ and corresponding eigenvector is $e_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$.  So $e_1$ can be taken as the first vector of canonical basis and we know that canonical form is $$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi \\
0 & \sin \varphi & \cos \varphi 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

*I cannot solve by myself rigorously the following questions:*

1) How to find the rest two vectors of canonical basis?

2) And which value of $\sin \varphi=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ I need to take?

I will highly appreciate your detailed answer! I was trying to think on this question for the last 2 days but I failed to solve rigorously.

Comment: Because $f$ is orthogonal, it preserves the angles between vectors. You have found an eigenvector $e_1$, and whenever $u$ is orthogonal to $e_1$, we have that $f(u)$ must be orthogonal to $e_1$ as well. Therefore the orthogonal complement of $e_1$ is preserved under $f$, since $f$ acts orthogonally on this plane it must be by a rotation. So pick any two orthonormal vectors in that plane. (There is no canonical way to pick these, the best you can possibly do is to take an orthonormal pair).

Comment: @Joppy, i reread your comment about 3-4 times and wanna ask you question: what do you mean by "preserved under $f$"? What you conclude from this?

Comment: If $f \colon V \to V$ is a linear operator and $W \subseteq V$ is a subspace, then we say that $W$ is preserved under $f$ if $f(W) \subseteq W$. For example, a rotation in 3D has two obvious such subspaces: one is the axis of rotation (the 1-eigenspace you found), and the other is the plane of rotation which is orthogonal to the axis.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two-dimensional subspace consisting of vectors orthogonal to $e_1$. On this two-dimensional subspace, $A_f$ acts as a rotation of angle $\varphi$. You can perform Gram-Schmidt on $e_1$ to find two other vectors $e_2$ and $e_3$ that together form an orthonormal basis. You can check that $A_f$ acts on $e_2$ and $e_3$ like the rotation matrix by $\varphi = \pi/3$ or $\varphi=-\pi/3$; I think the angle will flip if you negate $e_2$ or $e_3$, or if you swap the order of these two basis vectors.

---

Response to comments:

What my previous comment was saying is that if you are indeed familiar with the theorem and its proof, then you should be able to answer your questions. But anyway, a sketch: Joppy's comment shows you that the orthogonal complement of $e_1$ (the span of $e_2$ and $e_3$) is preserved by $f$; that is, if $u \in \text{span}\{e_2, e_3\}$, then $A_f u \in \text{span}\{e_2, e_3\}$. This is reflected in the block diagonal structure of your matrix in the new basis: the $1 \times 1$ block corresponds to how $A_f$ acts on the span of $e_1$, and the $2 \times 2$ block corresponds to how $A_f$ acts on the span of $e_2$ and $e_3$.

Because we chose $e_2$ and $e_3$ to be orthogonal, we know $A_f e_2$ and $A_f e_3$ must be orthogonal because $A_f$ is an orthogonal matrix. Thus, when restricted to this two-dimensional subspace, $A_f$ is an orthogonal transformation with determinant $+1$.

Then the question reduces to a two-dimensional problem. You may already know that [any orthogonal transformation on a two-dimensional space (with respect to an orthonormal basis) that has determinant $+1$ must be of the form $\begin{bmatrix} \cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi \\ \sin \varphi & \cos \varphi \end{bmatrix}$ for some $\varphi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924242/prove-that-all-2x2-orthogonal-matrices-can-be-expressed-as-rotation-or-reflectio). The choice of basis in this two-dimensional space will not change anything except possibly the value of $\varphi$.

---

With $e_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(0, 1, -1)$ and $e_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(2, -1, -1)$ we have
$$A_f e_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1, 1,0) = \frac{1}{2}  e_2 -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} e_3$$
$$A_f e_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(1,1,-2) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} e_2 + \frac{1}{2} e_3$$

Comment: I had the same idea that I have to find $e_2$ and $e_3$ in this way but how do we know that matrix of operator $f$ in $e_1,e_2,e_3$ have this matrix? To be honest, I need more details. Could you show the entire reasoning with details, please?

Comment: More precisely, I am a bit confused with your last sentence "You can that $A_f$...". Could you demonstrate it?

Comment: @ZFR I mean that once you find $e_2$ and $e_3$ in that way, check that $A_f e_2 = (\cos \varphi) e_2 + (\sin \varphi) e_3$ and $A_f e_3 = (-\sin \varphi) e_2 + (\sin \varphi) e_3$ for one of those two choices of $\varphi$.

Comment: But in general how to show that any pair of orthonormal vectors $e_2,e_3$ which are on the plane which is orthogonal to $e_1$ they satisfy $A_fe_2=(\cos \varphi)e_2+(\sin \varphi)e_3$ and $A_fe_3=(-\sin \varphi)e_2+(\cos \varphi)e_3$? Actually this is my question. I am interested in general case when $A_f$ is arbitrary orthogonal matrix $3\times 3$.

Comment: @ZFR Then this is the proof behind your first statement "we know that for any orthogonal operator (on $\mathbb{R}^3$) there is a canonical basis such that the operator $f$ in this basis is ..." which I assumed you were aware of since you were using that fact to solve this particular exercise. If your question is really about this abstract claim rather than this particular exercise with this particular matrix, I suggest you ask another question and be specific about what you wish to understand.

Comment: Yes i am aware of this theorem. So i wish to understand the following: i found the vector $e_1$. Then i can find also orthonormal vectors $e_2$ and $e_3$. How do you know that matrix of our operator $f$ in this basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$ has the desired form? Any choice of orthonormal pairs $e_2$ and $e_3$ will work?

Comment: @ZFR See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your edit but I am still confused. So we know canonical form of orthogonal matrix and we know the first vector of canonical basis. My goal is to find the rest two $e'_2$ and $e'_3$. how to find them rigorously? I really cannot understand this

Comment: @ZFR Use Gram-Schmidt to find an orthonormal basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ that includes $e_1$.

Comment: I have done this and but why $e'_2$ and $e'_3$ satisfies the above property? Namely $f(e'_2)=(\cos \varphi)e_2+(\sin \varphi)e_3$. I am really so confused about this.

Comment: @ZFR This is because $f$ is an orthogonal transformation (with determinant $1$) on the two-dimensional subspace $\text{span}\{e_2, e_3\}$. As the link in my last paragraph shows, any $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix with determinant $1$ has that form.

Comment: I do know that this is true, i.e. any orthogonal matrix with determinant 1 has this form. But..

Comment: For example, I can take $e_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(0,1,-1)$ and $e_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(2,-1,-1)$. But $f(e_2)$ is not the same $\cos \varphi\cdot e_2+\sin \varphi\cdot e_3$.

Comment: @ZFR See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we want to find some **orthogonal** $U$ such that $UA_fU^T$ has the desired form so 
that $(U A_f U^T)^T (U A_f U^T) = UA_f^TA_f U^T = I$.

Since it is normal we know that there is an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors.

Since it is orthogonal and real, one eigenvalue must be real hence equal to $\pm 1$.

It is not too hard to see that $A_f e = e$ where $e=(1,1,1)$.

By inspection, note that $v_2=(1,-1,0) , v_3=(1,1,-2)$ are orthogonal (not normal yet).
(Note that **any** two orthogonal vectors that lie in $e^\bot$ will do.)

If we let $U = \begin{bmatrix} {e \over \|e\|} & {v_1 \over \|v_1\|} & {v_2 \over \|v_2\|} 
 \end{bmatrix}$, then  $U^T A_f U$ has the form
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \\  & B  \end{bmatrix}$ and we must have $B^T B = I$.

Hence $B$ is a two dimensional rotation and $\det B = 1$ so it is proper (otherwise it would take a similar but slightly different form). Hence it has the form $\begin{bmatrix} c & -s \\ s & c  \end{bmatrix}$, where $c^2+s^2 = 1$ and from this
we can determine an angle.

If we grind through the computations we get
$UA_fU^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & & \\
 & {1 \over 2} &  -{\sqrt{3} \over 2} \\
& {\sqrt{3} \over 2} & {1 \over 2}  \end{bmatrix}$ and from this we
get $\theta = { \pi \over 3}$.